# Command 'update-manager' not found

Tags: updates, update-manager, 21.10, software-sources

I'm currently trying to update from 21.10 Impish Indri to Jammy Jellyfish but am unable due to update-manager somehow not being installed. I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance! :)

[My Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwqP.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: The official guide can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades (*~same detail as found in duplicate link*) and the Upgrade docs can be read via https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades  (*Though I'd also recommend reading the releases notes for the release you're going to, links can be found in announcement pages too*)

Comment: ps:  If you have trouble understanding the EOLUpgrades link, OR duplicate link on this site, the detail required is the output of `sudo apt update` ... ie. that is what you currently have to get working without any error(s) or warnings...  Then you can install the [Ubuntu Release Upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tools required inc. `update-manager`.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how to update my software sources or what it should even look like after I've done it by looking at the link you attatched, and that's the first step. I mean there's 63 lines in my sources.list alone so do I just delete the entire thing and paste the entire code box they have under the update sources list section?

Comment: No you don't delete *the entire thing*...   Using an example from my own system I have a line which reads `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted`   (I'm running *lunar* where you're on *impish*...  otherwise you to have a line that matches the line I picked (*at random*).   If my release (*lunar* had passed EOL I'd get an error on that line thus it would require change. The change is changing `http://archive.ubuntu.com` to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/`  ie. my line would thus look like `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted`

Comment: ie.  you'll note the only thing changed was the URL (`archive.ubuntu.com` changed to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`). That's what https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades tries to get you to do.  You may note I'm using the main archive (archive.ubuntu.com), if I was using my country mirror (`au.archive.ubuntu.com` as I'm an aussie) I'd also remove the `au.` as no country mirrors exist for old-releases.ubuntu.com